# How do I locate vendor files to 'import' using Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

So this is a really basic question.  In all my blueprinted files, I see `import` statements such as:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
```

Now I know that the build process is finding these in the vendor directory where `bower` installed them.  Recently, I added moment.js, and I'd like to create a helper using it.  However, there must be an additional naming convention that's being used because I can't simply

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

-- it claims it cannot find it in the tree merger.  What is the right way to tell Broccoli where to find things when I want to import them?

Comment: I struggled with this exact issue.  Check out the docs I wrote on this a few weeks ago for a step-by-step guide. https://github.com/josh-padnick/ember-cli/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2013-04-08-managing-dependencies.md#import-a-standard-non-amd-library

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got things to work.

- Install moment.js using `bower install`
- Add the following line in Brocfile.js

  ```
  app.import('vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js');
  ```
- In your code, you do NOT have to `import moment` as it is NOT a ES6 module. You can call moment directly. For example,

  ```
  var currDate = moment();
  ```
- In the files where you use moment, don't forget to add the below comment as the first line of your file. You need to do this to avoid the jshint errors shown by ember-cli when you build the code

  ```
  /* global moment:true */
  ```

Hope this helps!